# How to show more than 4 applications matching a search string in the Windows Start menu (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu, desktop-customization, user-interface

In Win7, how can you show more than 4 apps matching a search string entered into the Start menu's *"Search programs and files"* input field when Control Panel items also match the search string?

Note that I am referring to showing the matching app shortcuts within the Start menu, and not in a separate window.